# Singular vs. Plural bei Rückbezug auf „Anzahl”

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Weche der folgenden Varianten ist zu bevorzugen?

> Sie enthält eine Liste vorgegebener Antwortmöglichkeiten, von denen eine beliebige Anzahl korrekt sein **können**.
>
> Sie enthält eine Liste vorgegebener Antwortmöglichkeiten, von denen eine beliebige Anzahl korrekt sein **kann**.

Ich tendiere stark zur zweiten Variante, aber mehr aus rationalen Gründen und nicht weil der erste Satz für mich irgendwie falsch klingen würde.

Comment: Duden gibt übrigens Beispiele für beides: "eine ganze Anzahl Kinder/von Kindern kam/(seltener:) kamen uns entgegen" -> Beides richtig ;)

Comment: @Em1, das ist eine (zufällig die beste) Antwort, kein Kommentar. Takkat, löschen Sie!

Answer (score 4):

Ich denke, dass sich das Verb hier auf *die Anzahl* bezieht, weshalb ich den Singular bevorzugen würde. Wenn man *eine beliebige Anzahl*, wie in einem Kommentar zu der anderen Antwort vorgeschlagen, durch *zwei oder drei* ersetzt, klingt der Singular definitiv falsch:

> Verschiedene Antwortmöglichkeiten, von denen *zwei oder drei* richtig sein kann

Und der Plural richtig:

> Verschiedene Antwortmöglichkeiten, von denen *zwei oder drei* richtig sein können

Das Gegenteil ist der Fall, wenn man *Anzahl* durch *eine* ersetzt:
Klingt falsch:

> Verschiedene Antwortmöglichkeiten, von denen *eine* richtig sein können

Klingt richtig:

> Verschiedene Antwortmöglichkeiten, von denen *eine* richtig sein kann.

Deshalb denke ich, dass sich *kann/können* hier auf *zwei oder drei* beziehungsweise *eine* bezieht, und somit im ursprünglichen Satz auf *Anzahl*.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde sagen Plural. Das Verb im Nebensatz bezieht sich auf *Antwortmöglichkeiten* und nicht auf *Anzahl*. Man tendiert intuitiv zu  *kann*, da *Anzahl* näher am Verb ist, aber das ist rein grammatikalisch nicht entscheidend.

Edit:
Der Kommentar von EM1 unter der Frage ist die beste Antwort.

Comment: Kernpunkt der Frage war: "Plural oder Singular?" – Ist deine Antwort jetzt, dass Singular und nur Singular richtig ist?

Comment: @Em1 Sehr guter Einwand. Habe nochmal genau darueber nachgedacht und meine Antwort korrigiert.

Comment: Es koennte helfen wenn man im Kopf "eine beliebige Anzahl" durch "zwei oder drei" ersetzt.

Comment: Ich bin mir noch nicht sicher, ob ich dem zustimme: "Eine beliebige Anzahl (von Antwortmöglichkeiten) ist richtig". Das "von Antwortmöglichkeiten" ist nicht notwendig, daher in Klammern. Man kann das ganze nicht mit "zwei oder drei" ersetzen. ABER: Zwei oder drei der Antwortmöglichkeiten sind richtig.