# What is the best way to say "a large number of [noun]" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, idiomaticity

In my current project I want to translate the phrase "a large number of tents are set up." This is part of the text of a video game, specifically the narration. But looking at [dict.cc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dict.cc), I see numerous ways to say "number of [something]":

- Anzahl von [noun]
- Anzahl an [noun]
- Anzahl der [noun]
- Zahl der [noun]
- [noun]zahl
- Reihe von [noun]

I do not know which to use as I am not sure how these differ, if at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a very easy and natural way of using *Anzahl* that you didn't mention:

- eine Anzahl [noun]

You just use *Anzahl* and then, directly following, the noun in nominative or genitive case. It can be used just like a measurement unit, e.g. "ein Kilo Erbsen" or "drei Paletten Radios".

> Eine große Anzahl Zelte wird aufgebaut.
> Die Jugendlichen schliefen in einer großen Anzahl Zelte, die direkt hinter dem Strand aufgestellt worden waren.

Comments on the options that were mentioned in the question:

- Anzahl von [noun]

It's not wrong, but I would avoid this and use:

- Anzahl an [noun]

This is the preposition to use if you want to use a preposition for some reason.

- Anzahl der [noun]

You use this if you want to refer to a definite set of [noun] with a definite article, like in:

> Die Anzahl *der* Fahrraddiebstähle, *bei denen* kein Täter ermittelt werden kann, steigt seit Jahren.

- Zahl der [noun]

equivalent to Anzahl, there's no real difference. The use without article or prepositions (*eine Zahl Zelte*) is uncommon with "Zahl" though.

- [noun]zahl

Yes, you can create that or use it if you know that it is already in use, but you would normally only create that if you really want it to be a term that's going to be used at least a few times. For example, if you write a study comparing scout summer camps, you might want to refer to their "Zeltzahl" in your statistics.

- Reihe von [noun]

This is derived from the meaning *"a row of ..."* and it doesn't talk about a number at all, it's basically synonymous to "some". You can also just use this with a noun in nominative: "eine Reihe Zelte".

Comment: The comparison to a number of measurement is misleading since after numbers of measurement the measured thing stands in the grammatical singular, after *große Anzahl* the genitive plural is required.

Comment: @SirCornflakes Both statements are wrong. 1) From Duden - Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 6. Aufl.: "Nach Anzahl kann das Gezählte im Genitiv oder als Apposition stehen: eine Anzahl Kinder; mit einer Anzahl Schafe. Eine Anzahl [steinreicher] Industrieller/ (auch möglich:) [steinreiche] Industrielle stimmte dagegen." 2) Whether the noun after a mesurement unit needs to be singular or plural depends on the noun (countable vs. uncountable): "ein Kilo Erbsen" oder "drei Paletten Radios". I did use only uncountable nouns as examples, which could be confusing, so I edited.

Comment: I would add that "eine ganze Reihe von Vorfällen" can be used to describe a number of events. Or "eine Reihe unterschiedlichster Firmen" to describe a number of things - but its usage is more nuanced than the others.

Answer (score 14):

None of your given translations has a counterpart for **large**.

The simplest variant would of course be *viele [noun]*, e. g. *viele Zelte*.

Note, that *eine Reihe von* corresponds to *a few* or *a couple of*, so the number is below large.

Comment: "eine Reihe" is especially used in cases where a few are already an unusual high number. More like "several". "Er hatte eine ganze Reihe guter Ideen" colloquially implies a larger than average number of good ideas.

Answer (score 9):

I think the most natural translation for

> A large number of tents are set up.

is

> Zahlreiche Zelte werden aufgebaut.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but doesn't "to be set up" mean that the tents are already there, i.e., building them has already finished? If that is indeed the case, "... wurden aufgebaut" might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Heinzi: Ich weiß nur, dass ich die gleiche Meinung wie der Google-Übersetzer habe.

Comment: As a non-native English speaker but someone in IT that regularly sets up things, I would agree with the answer. Cambridge Dictionary seems to agree: "to prepare something for use, especially by putting the different parts of it together" (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/set-up)

Comment: Yeah if you mean "... werden aufgebaut" then you could put "... are being set up".

Comment: Do you think "Eine Menge von Zelten" works okay as well?

Comment: @Lorraine: I do, _»eine Menge«_ and _»jede Menge«_ are more colloquial.

Comment: @YetiCGN: Sure, that's what "to set up" (aufbauen) means. But I would translate "to **be** set up" as "aufgebaut **sein**", which means that setting it up already finished.

Comment: @Heinzi But this is the passive use of "to set up" and not active "to be set up". Otherwise it would be "the tents are being set up".

Comment: @YetiCGN: That's exactly my point: "The tents are being set up" -> "Die Zelte werden aufgebaut". "The tents are set up" -> "Die Zelte sind aufgebaut". The sentence in the question is the latter.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds eloquent to say:

- eine Vielzahl von [noun]

*Eine Vielzahl von Zelten wurde aufgestellt.* In my mind, this evokes the image of a site with many *different* tents, like a campground. If the tents all look the same, like at a base camp, I would rather say: *Eine große Anzahl von Zelten wurde aufgestellt.*

Comment: Good suggestion, and good observation regarding *Vielzahl.*

Answer (score 4):

> A large number of tents are set up there.

For quantifyable numbers, use *Zahl*, not *Anzahl*:

> *Eine große Zahl Zelte steht dort.*

I prefer that one. Another option is:

> *Eine große Zahl von Zelten steht dort.*

*Anzahl* on the other hand is outright indefinite.

> Eine Anzahl Zelte steht dort.
>
> A number of tents are set up there.

*Anzahl* means *we don't even attempt to count them* and that usually because it's a small number and someone could easily double it by counting again and find those hidden behind others.

Comment: I see you used "steht" for "are set up." Is it not idiomatic to say "Eine große Zahl Zelten sind dort aufgestellt?"

Comment: No, that's very unidiomatic and I would suspect someone translated that from English.

Comment: "[...] Zelte sind dort aufgestellt" is fine. Examples: ["Zwei große Zelte sind dort aufgestellt"](https://www.dasgelbeblatt.de/lokales/miesbach/-92270344.html), ["Etliche Zelte sind dort aufgestellt"](https://www.explorermagazin.de/skand/spitzber161.htm). You can find many other examples on the web. The "**n**" in your "Eine große Zahl Zelte**n** sind dort aufgestellt" is wrong though, "Zelte" is correct. And I feel "Viele Zelte sind dort aufgestellt" is more idiomatic, "eine große Zahl" feels a bit stilted in this case.

Comment: @jcsahnwaldtReinstateMonica your comment contradicts some of the upvoted answers, they claim it should be ,,Eine grosse Zahl Zelte ist dort aufgestellt", with ,,ist" referring to ,,die Zahl". Which is correct?

Comment: Both are okay. German is a bit wonky with singular terms for multiple objects.

Comment: I'm not sure that *Anzahl* means we dont even attempt to count. *Eine kleine/große/stattliche/enorme etc. Anzahl* sounds perfectly fine to me. Duden even has the example *die Anzahl der Teilnehmer war nicht ausreichend* which seems to actually require counting.

Comment: Eine große Zahl? That sounds wonky. I think _Eine große Anzahl_ sounds much more natural.

Comment: In my ideolect I'd prefer *Anzahl* over *Zahl* here, but *Zahl* is definitley fine, too. Even *Menge*  works, although tents are countable.

Comment: @ToivoSäwén: Now that I think about it, I'd agree that "ist" is technically correct, since it refers to the singular "Zahl". But as Janka said, the rules seem to be a bit relaxed in such cases. See e.g. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23120/singular-vs-plural-bei-rückbezug-auf-anzahl

Answer (score 4):

If you know the approximate number, you could also use "Dutzende", "Hunderte", "Tausende", which would sound very natural to a German.

Hunderte Soldaten errichteten Dutzende Zelte auf der Wiese, begleitet von Tausenden Einwohnern, die sich das Spektakel nicht entgehen lassen wollten.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not German so I can't say with certainty, but I think I have heard the phrase "jede Menge" many times to indicate a large amount of something. So like

> Jede Menge Zelte sind aufgebaut

I think it's a very informal way of saying it, but maybe a native German here can confirm if it sounds natural.

Comment: While *jede Menge* it is very idiomatic I feel that it does not match the somewhat formal expression "large number" because, as you say, it is rather casual.

Answer (score 2):

"Eine Unmenge von Zelten" would imply a very large number.  Strictly speaking, "Unmenge" is a negation of "Menge", and "eine Menge von Zelten" would mean "a lot of tents" in the usual meaning, and "a set of tents" in the mathematical meaning.

The implication of "Unmenge" is that you would not be able to count or specify it due to its size, so it is quite stronger than the comparatively lacklustre "eine Menge von Zelten".

An adjective you could employ in a similar meaning would be "unzählige Zelte" or also "unzählbare".  Again, this means too large to count: if there are other reasons for an entity being not countable, you'd use "nicht zählbare" instead.  Here the negations "un-" and "nicht" carry quite different connotations.

Comment: This seems to me more as a comment to a different answer, not an answer in itself. The question did not mention "Unmenge" or "Zelte". Auch bestreite ich, dass man eine Unmenge nicht zählen kann. Gerade Zelte haben sich oft als abzählbar erwiesen. Und im direkten Zusammenhang, wenn jmd. sagt: "Eine Menge an Wassereis und eine Unmenge als MIlcheis." - dann würde es für wahrscheinlich halten, dass damit ausgedrückt werden soll, es habe mehr Milcheis als Wassereis gegeben. Ansonsten sehe ich die Implikation nicht als gegeben.

Answer (score 1):

While it seems more natural to simply say *zahlreiche/viele Zelte*, the same is true in English: These adjectives have direct equivalents in "numerous/many", and simply saying "many tents" is a simpler and perhaps a bit less formal.

For example, I'd expect a police report about a crowd use "large number of participants", and in German *"große Anzahl von Teilnehmern"* instead of simply saying "many" resp. *"viele".*

Therefore, in order to preserve the somewhat elaborate style, I'd go with the direct translation of ***eine große Zahl/Anzahl von Zelten.*** In my opinion both word choices are equally good, and the semantic difference is minimal to nonexistent.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add a little bit of detail, in the construction

*Eine große Anzahl [noun]*

the noun is formally in the genitive plural. this can be easily seen when you add an adjective to the noun as in

*Eine große Anzahl junger Menschen*

It is also visible when the noun is a nominalised adjective or participle:

*Eine große Anzahl Delegierter*